# iOS UDP socket receive delays using multicast addr and port

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, macos, sockets

I'm using a MacBook Pro to send a series of 1024-byte UDP datagrams in my main thread over a socket using a multicast address and port every 12 mS (ugly but illustrative):

```
for(;;) {
//-------------- Send ----------------
    try {
        sock.sendTo(filebufPos, readsize, mcAddr, mcPort);
        sendCount++;
        if(sendCount < sends_needed) {
            filebufPos += readsize;
        } else {
            sendCount = 0;          //Reset send counter
            filebufPos = filebuf;   //Reset pointer to start of file buffer
        }
    } catch (SocketException &e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
    usleep(12000);   //------------ Pause between sends-----------
}
```

On my iPhone 5, I try to receive the datagrams using a non-blocking 'recvFrom' call on the same multicast address and port within a callback routine that gets called every 1.5 mS, ala:

```
try {
    nBytesReceived = sock->recvFrom((void *)buf, nBytesCount, mcAddr, mcPort);
} catch (SocketException &e) {
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

I measure the time between successful UDP socket recvs on the iPhone client side. Ideally, I should receive the UDP datagrams every 8 callbacks (12 ms), and for the most part this is the case. However, sometimes the time between recvs is very short, while at other times it can be as long as 100-150 mS between recvs.

Any ideas why this might be happening?
Thanks!

Comment: just sounds like a non-real time OS being a non-real time OS to me,, for both parties. The kernel is free to go out to lunch and take care of itself when it wants. For the times between recvs being very short,, I'd guess that comes after the recvs being long and the receiver has buffered up the packets so there's some immediately ready for the next `recvFrom` call.

Comment: The received packets are definitely being buffered, but this doesn't happen all the time. This plays havoc with my trIs there any way to increase the timing reliability of the socket recvs? Does thread priority enter into this behavior at all?

Comment: [Sorry, previous post incomplete :-( Should have been:   The received packets are definitely being buffered, but this doesn't happen all the time. What would cause the system to sometimes buffer packets and other times not? Is there any way to increase the timing reliability of the socket recvs? Does thread priority enter into this behavior at all?

Comment: certainly no expert with this stuff, but if you need a very precise schedule you're going to need an OS that supports that. OSes meant for general consumer consumption (Mac OS X, Windows, flavors of LInux, etc) are not going to support real time operation. Boosting thread priority surely can help, but be warned that if you boost it too high and it gets schedule priority over some necessary process to keep the kernel alive, you could end up with system stability issues. AFAIK, any system call from user space down to the kernel is essentially a software interrupt that says, "Hey kernel, ...

Comment: ... when you get a chance, could you do something for me?" (allocate memory, send data over a socket as in your case, etc). Sometimes the kernel may be ready right then, maybe it won't be ready until 200us from now, or even 30ms from now. For your grandma browsing the web or student typing a term paper, this is just fine. They're not going to care if packets are sent right now or 30ms from now. For flying a space probe or running a nuclear plant, this probably isn't good enough. If you _really need_ these tight tolerances, you're going to have to investigate a much more real-time approach.